# Need correct step for Bat file creation using (TestNG.xml + Maven)

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am wondering about to create correct **Bat file** ,

I am using **Maven + Selenium(TestNG)**

I have tried many different ways to Resolve exception, But its one of the most common exception: **Could not find or load main class / java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**

In my Maven project **there is no bin or lib folder**, And I am wondering for it. Whether to call library from .m2(Maven) installation.

To call class file, In my maven project .class file located something like : `E:\testBatchDemo\target\classes\mytest`

Here is sample of What I have tried so far,

```
set projectLocation=E:\testBatchDemo
cd %projectLocation%   
set classpath=E:\testBatchDemo\target\classes\mytest; 
java -cp %classpath% C:\Users\Desktop-pc\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.14.3\testng-6.14.3.jar; C:\Users\Desktop-pc\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.12.0\selenium-java-3.12.0.jar; org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
pause
```

Anyone can please assist, Which library need to call or How can I achieve correct .class path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question description I think there are certain grey areas which we need to address beofre jumping into the solution.

- *I am wondering about to create correct `batch` (i.e. `.bat`) file*: Fundamentally, [**Maven**](https://maven.apache.org/) is a *build tool* which extensively works in-conjunction with `pom.xml` and doesn't requires any *Windows batch* file.
- Moving forward if your *usecase* is to pass the *Windows batch* file to [**Jenkins**](https://jenkins.io/) for **Continous Integration** then you need to verify this step if the *Windows batch* file is able to kick-start the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- However *Jenkins* can also kick-start the execution of your *Test Suite* through the `pom.xml` and *Maven*.

Now, your *usecase* must match to one of the above mentioned requirement as mentioned below:

- **Windows Batch file** + **TestNG**
- **Jenkins** + **TestNG**
- **Jenkins** + **Maven**

As you have extensively spoken about the *Windows batch* file so here are the relevant details as per the first option **Windows Batch file** + **TestNG**:

- Write a simple code block with `@Test` annotation of *TestNG* as follows:

  ```
  package demoJenkins;

  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class DemoJenkinsJob 
  {

      @Test
      public void testJenkins()
      {

          System.out.println("Welcome to Jenkins World");
      }
  }
  ```
- *Run As* `TestNG Test`
- On Successful execution convert using `TestNG -> Convert to TestNG` and `testng.xml` gets created.
- The `testng.xml` will look like:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  <suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
      <classes>
        <class name="demoJenkins.DemoJenkinsJob"/>
      </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
  ```
- Get the absolute *Project Location* from your *IDE* (i.e. *Eclipse*), browse to the sub-directory, create a directory **lib**
- Copy all the relevant jars and libraries (**Selenium** and **TestNG** jars) in the **lib** directory.

  - `selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar`
  - `org.testng_6.14.2.r201802161450.jar`
  - `com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar`
  - `org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar`
  - `org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.17.0.jar`
- Through *CLI* browse to the *Project Directory* and provide the following *classpath*:

  ```
  >set classpath=<Project Directory>\bin;<Project Directory>\lib\*;
  ```
- Through *CLI* execute `testng.xml` as follows:

  ```
  Project_Directory>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```
- On successful execution, within the *Project Directory* create a new text document and add the following code:

  ```
  java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```
- Save the file as **run.bat**
- Execute the *Windows batch* file **run.bat** and verify it executes the *Test Suite* as expected.

---

### Update

As per your question and subsequent comment,

- When you use *TestNG* and/or *Maven*, these framework/buildtool keeps all the relevant *jars* in their respective location. But when you intend the configure the *buildpath* manually you have to create the **lib** directory manually and keep a copy of the relevant *jars*.
- Perhaps you don't need to create the **bin** directory manually as on successful compilation of your *Java program* your program will automatically create the *bin* and keeps the *class* file before *execution*.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I will execute step by step. Can you please check for Bin folder which usually contains .class file?  in my case bin folder is not there, So i am calling target folder.

Comment: @IshitaShah Updated my answer, let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: I am able to execute Test Suite by calling pom.xml