# Unable to run xml test suite from command prompt

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, command-prompt

I have TestNG suite with 2 tests included into an XML file. Test Suite works just fine if launching via IDE ( Eclipse ). However, I do need to run via command prompt.  I try launching it using the following command:

```
java -cp C:\eclipse\plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.9.5.201505251947\lib\*;C:\myworkspace\myproject\bin org.testng.TestNG MyTestSuite.xml
```

The error that occurs is:

```
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class tests.Test1

[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class tests.MyTest1 - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class tests.Test2

[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class tests.MyTest2 - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

TestNG also reports 0 test runs with 0 failures and 0 skips if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the *Test Suite* works just fine if launching via IDE ( Eclipse ) you can follow the below mentioned steps to execute the *Test Suite* through command prompt:

### Steps

- Get the absolute *Project Location* from your *IDE* (i.e. *Eclipse*), browse to the sub-directory and create a directory **lib**
- Copy all the relevant jars and libraries (**Selenium** and **TestNG** jars) in the **lib** directory.

  - `selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar`
  - `org.testng_6.14.2.r201802161450.jar`
  - `com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar`
  - `org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar`
  - `org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.17.0.jar`
- Through *CLI* browse to the *Project Directory* and provide the following *classpath*:

  ```
  >set classpath=<Project Directory>\bin;<Project Directory>\lib\*;
  ```
- Through *CLI* execute `testng.xml` as follows:

  ```
  Project_Directory>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```
- On successful execution, within the *Project Directory* create a new text document and add the following code:

  ```
  java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```
- Save the file as **run.bat**
- Execute the *Windows batch* file **run.bat** and verify it executes the *Test Suite* as expected.

> You can find a detailed relevant discussion in [Need correct step for Bat file creation using (TestNG.xml + Maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081849/need-correct-step-for-bat-file-creation-using-testng-xml-maven/51084290#51084290)

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks fine.

This should work for you :

1. After adding **TestNG** to your project library create one folder in
   your Project names as lib ( name can be anything ).
2. Go to "`C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins`" location and copy `com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar` and `org.testng_6.14.2.r20180216145.jar` file to created folder (lib).

Note : Files are **testng.jar** and **jcommander.jar**